# Spring Boot: remove jsessionid from url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat8

How can I remove the jsessionid from my urls?

I'm using Spring Boot MVC (without Spring Security; tomcat embedded).

I've read that It could be done by setting the disableUrlRewriting to "true".
But this looks like a Spring Security solution, which I don't use (it's a simple project without login; just pages; a session-controller exists and has to be a session-controller).

I'm asking this because GoogleBot is creating urls containing the id.

EDIT:
I solved it with the solution described at: https://randomcoder.org/articles/jsessionid-considered-harmful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created a quick-and-dirty spring-boot app and here's what I came up with.

The ServletInitializer that is generated, you can alter it in this fashion:

```
package com.division6.bootr;

import java.util.Collections;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.SessionCookieConfig;
import javax.servlet.SessionTrackingMode;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // This can be done here or as the last step in the method
        // Doing it in this order will initialize the Spring
        // Framework first, doing it as last step will initialize
        // the Spring Framework after the Servlet configuration is 
        // established
        super.onStartup(servletContext);

        // This will set to use COOKIE only
        servletContext
            .setSessionTrackingModes(
                Collections.singleton(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE)
        );
        // This will prevent any JS on the page from accessing the
        // cookie - it will only be used/accessed by the HTTP transport
        // mechanism in use
        SessionCookieConfig sessionCookieConfig=
                servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig();
        sessionCookieConfig.setHttpOnly(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootrApplication.class);
    }

}
```

**AUTHOR NOTE**

I am not 100% sure when this was introduced but by introducing the following parameters, the same can be accomplished without having to write code:

- server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=true
- server.servlet.session.tracking-modes=cookie

Answer (score 13):

As this question is in spring boot context, easy solution for me was:

```
server:
  session:
    tracking-modes: cookie
```

after spring 2 onwards

```
server:
  servlet
    session:
      tracking-modes: cookie
```

Added in appication.yml it modifies embedded tomcat config. From list of ll spring boot properties:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

Comment: spring-boot 2.0 should be `server.servlet.session.tracking-modes=cookie`, check @DaveG 's answer above.

Answer (score 4):

you can also try this,

```
        @Bean
            public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
                return new ServletContextInitializer() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
                       servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(Collections.singleton(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE));
                       SessionCookieConfig sessionCookieConfig=servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig();
                       sessionCookieConfig.setHttpOnly(true);
                    }
                };

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

More portable option which also works for non-SpringBoot, add the following to the webapp's `web.xml`:

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```