# Toggle Spring Security for the requests with particular Request Header

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to **toggle/bypass/disable Spring Security** (Authentication and Authorization) **for** all the **requests** **having particular Request Header**.

For example, if a request url is hit with that Request Header, Spring Security should be bypassed, if not it should not be bypassed.

For this, I am using following *requestMatchers* Spring Security config:

```
@Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET)
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
        .requestMatchers(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("TEST-HEADER","TEST-VALUE"));
  }
```

My remaining Security Config is :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity (prePostEnabled = true)
@ConditionalOnProperty (name = "security.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private SecurityProps securityProps;

  @Autowired
  private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private MyAuthenticationEntryPoint myAuthenticationEntryPoint;

  @Autowired
  private MyCORSFilter myCORSFilter;

  public SecurityConfig() {
    SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
  }


  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(myCORSFilter, SessionManagementFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(requestHeaderFilter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authenticationProvider(preauthAuthProvider())
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, securityProps.getNoAuthGetPattern()).permitAll()
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, securityProps.getNoAuthOptionsPattern()).permitAll()
          .requestMatchers(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("TEST-HEADER","TEST-VALUE")).permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(myAuthenticationEntryPoint);
  }

  @Autowired
  @Override
  protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(preauthAuthProvider());
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET)
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
        .requestMatchers(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("TEST-HEADER","TEST-VALUE"));
  }

  public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderFilter() throws Exception {
    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
    requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setPrincipalRequestHeader(MySecurityConstants.LOGIN_HEADER);
    requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(false);
    requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
          AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (exception instanceof MySecurityException) {
          myAuthenticationEntryPoint.commenceMySecurityException(request, response, (MySecurityException) exception);
        } else if (exception instanceof UsernameNotFoundException) {
          myAuthenticationEntryPoint.commenceUsernameNotFoundException(request, response,
              (UsernameNotFoundException) exception);
        } else if (exception instanceof PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException) {
          myAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence(request, response, exception);
        }
      }
    });
    return requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter;
  }

  @Bean
  public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider() throws Exception {
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceWrapper());
    return authProvider;
  }

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> userDetailsServiceWrapper()
      throws Exception {
    UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> wrapper =
        new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<>();
    wrapper.setUserDetailsService(ivyUserDetailsService);
    return wrapper;
  }

}
```

With the above settings, I am **unable to disable/bypass Spring Security** and I am **getting** the **AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException** exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

Can anyone help me by identifying what am I doing wrong? Is my approach correct or I need to do something else to achieve this?

**EDIT :** 
I am getting this exception in `org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor` class in `beforeInvocation()` method where it tries to get the *authentication* object from **SecurityContextHolder**. `AbstractSecurityInterceptor` is invoked by its subclass `MethodSecurityInterceptor` which is invoked from my **Spring Controller** which is annotated with `@PreAuthorize`.

Comment: Where do you get the exception? Could you add the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @dur I have updated the question with details where I am getting the exception. The stacktraceElement array is of size 0 so stack trace is not available. Just getting the exception message that I have mentioned in question.

Comment: Are your `GET` methods annotated with `PreAuthorize`, too? You should get the same exception for `GET` methods.

Comment: No. GET methods are not annotated with PreAuthorize.

Comment: That's the reason, why it is working with `GET`methods. If you disable Spring Security for some URLs, you cannot use method security for that URLs. Instead of ignoring the URLs you have to permit these URLs.

Comment: I understood why GET is working. But, what I need is only request with particular Request Header should bypass security, if that Header is not passed it should not bypass security. I will update the question for the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176699/discussion-between-sahil-chhabra-and-dur).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your bypass is working fine. Its skipping the check.

**The security's authorization check part gets the authenticated object from SecurityContext, which will be set when a request gets through the spring security filter.**

So when you skip security filter SecurityContext is not set yet thus the error

You can do something like this to set it manually for your Custom Header Case

```
try {
    SecurityContext ctx = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(ctx);
    ctx.setAuthentication(event.getAuthentication());
} finally {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Answering all the queries.

> But if thats the case, then I guess all GET call should also have
>   failed, but my GET calls are working fine.

Since you have added this line All your GET calls are skipped from security check.

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, securityProps.getNoAuthGetPattern()).permitAll()
```

> where can I add the code you have mentioned? Any particular filter or
>   somewhere else ?

I have done something like this in a Filter. 
Refer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691187/spring-security-sessions-without-cookies/50857373#50857373)

Look at `TokenAuthenticationFilter` Class in Answer. Where am manually setting.

**Note: Its JWT implementation but good to refer**

```
UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
if (tokenHelper.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
    // create authentication
    TokenBasedAuthentication authentication = new TokenBasedAuthentication(userDetails);
    authentication.setToken(authToken);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}
```

> What is event in your answer?

I just got that case from Some Answer, cant find its link now. But you can `setAuthentication` like this or like above

```
Authentication authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken("system", null);
authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
context.setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if thats the case, then I guess all GET call should also have failed, but my GET calls are working fine. Anyways, where can I add the code you have mentioned? Any particular filter or somewhere else? What is event in your answer?

Comment: Thanks again. I will give it a try. But, still as per your reason why it is working for GET and not with Header, if I add permitAll() for .requestMatchers(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("TEST-HEADER","TEST-VALUE")) in HttpSecurity config just like for the GET. Its giving me the same error. Updated the question for reference.

Comment: That's good Point....   As per this it should allow. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestHeaderRequestMatcher.html  ...