# Spring Boot: RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"

Tags: spring, google-chrome, spring-boot, spring-security

I get the following exception when I POST the login credentials for my Spring Boot app.

> org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"

It is posting to `/dologin` and then redirecting to `/home` with the `jsessionid` appended to the end. It does also set the session cookie too. I did not change any session settings and there is no mention of `session` in `application.properties`.

I tried to set

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=true
server.servlet.session.tracking-modes=cookie
```

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31792535/148844, but it didn't work.

I added

```
@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
    return new ServletContextInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
           servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(Collections.singleton(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE));
           SessionCookieConfig sessionCookieConfig=servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig();
           sessionCookieConfig.setHttpOnly(true);
        }
    };
}
```

But now it just POSTs, sets the cookie, and redirects back to the login screen. It's as if it can't access the session.

I set `server.session.tracking-modes=cookie` (instead of `server.servlet...`) and it is only using cookies now, but the Chrome browser is not sending the cookie back to the server after login! `/home` action will only re-display the login page if `user` attribute in the session is null.

```
POST /dologin HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Referer: http://localhost:8080/home

HTTP/1.1 302
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=3B82AAA40CE94FF490FBF7B4DBD837DD; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: http://localhost:8080/home

GET /home HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Referer: http://localhost:8080/home

HTTP/1.1 200
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=B60BF649068F7E85346691FD2F5D119B; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 2742
Date: Sat, 29 Sep 2018 17:41:55 GMT
```

Notice the cookies are different and Chrome did not send the cookie back to the server? Why?

Spring Boot 1.5.13, Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @dur There is no `SpringSecurityConfiguration`. Do you mean `OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`? OAuth2 is working.

Comment: Ok, you are righr, it is just a configuration problem with Spring Boot, you method is not important.

Comment: Try to change the property to `server.session.tracking-modes`, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK changing `server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=true` to `server.session.tracking-modes=cookie` and changing `http://localhost:8080` to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` worked. I found this answer:

[Chrome localhost cookie not being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346919/chrome-localhost-cookie-not-being-set#7369084)

It seems Chrome keeps flipping from allowing `localhost` to disallowing `localhost`. It was working about a month or three ago. `localhost` is working for a Rails app and Chrome is sending the cookies.

In fact, Chrome is also sending the `_mt_rails_session` Rails cookie for `localhost` to the Spring Boot app, but never the `JSESSIONID` cookie.

I suspect, but have not confirmed, it may be due to setting up HTTPS on port 8080 for an unrelated 3rd Spring Boot app, and there may be some HSTS setting cached in Chrome internals. It's probably a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you!  The non-deprecated form is now `server.servlet.session.tracking-modes=cookie`

Comment: Thank you! This is also useful when using wkhtmltopdf with basic http authentication.