# Page hangs in 'PreLoader'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, thymeleaf

I'm trying to develop a user registration and login system.

When loading the page, it hangs in the preloader without showing the content.

I loaded the page after commenting out the preloader part in my Thymeleaf page and works fine.

I can't find why is this happening, a little help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

HTML code segment:

```html
        <!-- Page Preloder -->
    
    <div id="preloder">
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS code segment:

```
/* Preloder */

#preloder {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
    background: #000;
}

.loader {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -13px;
    margin-left: -13px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        border: 4px solid #f44336;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        border: 4px solid #673ab7;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        border: 4px solid #f44336;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        border: 4px solid #f44336;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        border: 4px solid #673ab7;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        border: 4px solid #f44336;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
}

.elements-section {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.el-title {
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.element {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.element:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

js code segment:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    /*------------------
        Preloder
    --------------------*/
    $(".loader").fadeOut();
    $("#preloder").delay(400).fadeOut("slow");

});
```

Comment: Would you mind [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the grey checkmark in my answer. If i have solved the question and provided a working solution. Thanks

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Sorry for the late reply. I updated the code according to your answer but an exception was thrown `org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "//"`

Comment: Hi no worries. That error is not definitely not from because we added `$('document').ready(function() {})` - There something else going with some URL. Can you make sure you wrap add your jQuery only code inside document ready. Let me know.

Comment: There are answers here for the error you are getting: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453980/spring-5-0-3-requestrejectedexception-the-request-was-rejected-because-the-url OR this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566368/spring-boot-requestrejectedexception-the-request-was-rejected-because-the-url / there errors are because we added DOM ready function

Comment: Any update here - is this all fixed now.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping nah dude :/. What did you meant by this `Can you make sure you wrap add your jQuery only code inside document ready`

Comment: I am not sure how to help further. You need to fix up your spring configurations

Comment: Have to refered to the question i have added above ? Because the answer i have provided below is not related to what you have mentioned as an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQuery [DOM ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function to make sure you `.loader` is `hiding` as window `load` function expect an event to be `triggered` in your case there is **no** event i.e `click` or `change`.

This will ensure you are `scripts` are getting executed when `DOM` is ready.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  /*------------------
      Preloder
  --------------------*/
  $(".loader").fadeOut();
  $("#preloder").delay(400).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```css
/* Preloder */

#preloder {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999999;
  background: #000;
}

.loader {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -13px;
  margin-left: -13px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    border: 4px solid #f44336;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    border: 4px solid #673ab7;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    border: 4px solid #f44336;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    border: 4px solid #f44336;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    border: 4px solid #673ab7;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    border: 4px solid #f44336;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}

.elements-section {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.el-title {
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.element {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.element:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloder">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```